# Strange issue in quarkus pod initialization after openshift cluster starts

Tags: openshift, keycloak, quarkus

I'm using quarkus oidc to protect a resource through keycloak. This is the code used:

```
@Path("/api")
public class NamasteResource {

    @Inject
    JsonWebToken jwt;

    @GET
    @Path("health")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String health() {
        return "I'm ok";
    }

    @GET
    @RolesAllowed("USERS")
    @Path("namaste-secured")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String namasteSecured() {
    String userName = jwt.getName();
        return "Hello " + userName;
    }
}
```

The health resource is used for pod's readiness probe.
The issue here is that when openshift cluster starts and pod is deployed, I get an internal server error and the application doesn't work anymore. This is the exception trace:

> 2021-06-24 01:59:44,457 ERROR [io.qua.ver.htt.run.QuarkusErrorHandler] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) HTTP Request to /api/health failed, error id: 80e18320-2973-48c6-a377-edfc0f1db56b-1: io.quarkus.oidc.OIDCException: Tenant configuration has not been resolved
> at io.quarkus.oidc.runtime.OidcAuthenticationMechanism.resolve(OidcAuthenticationMechanism.java:61)
> at io.quarkus.oidc.runtime.OidcAuthenticationMechanism.authenticate(OidcAuthenticationMechanism.java:40)
> at io.quarkus.oidc.runtime.OidcAuthenticationMechanism_ClientProxy.authenticate(OidcAuthenticationMechanism_ClientProxy.zig:189)
> at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.security.HttpAuthenticator.attemptAuthentication(HttpAuthenticator.java:100)
> at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.security.HttpAuthenticator_ClientProxy.attemptAuthentication(HttpAuthenticator_ClientProxy.zig:157)
> at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.security.HttpSecurityRecorder$2.handle(HttpSecurityRecorder.java:101)
> at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.security.HttpSecurityRecorder$2.handle(HttpSecurityRecorder.java:51)
> at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1038)
> at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:137)
> at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:132)
> at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.cors.CORSFilter.handle(CORSFilter.java:92)
> at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.cors.CORSFilter.handle(CORSFilter.java:18)
> at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1038)
> at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:137)
> at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:132)
> at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouterImpl.handle(RouterImpl.java:54)
> at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouterImpl.handle(RouterImpl.java:36)
> at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$9.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:426)
> at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$9.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:423)
> at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$1.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:149)
> at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$1.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:131)
> at io.vertx.core.http.impl.WebSocketRequestHandler.handle(WebSocketRequestHandler.java:50)
> at io.vertx.core.http.impl.WebSocketRequestHandler.handle(WebSocketRequestHandler.java:32)
> at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerConnection.handleMessage(Http1xServerConnection.java:136)
> at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.executeTask(ContextImpl.java:366)
> at io.vertx.core.impl.EventLoopContext.execute(EventLoopContext.java:43)
> at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.executeFromIO(ContextImpl.java:229)
> at io.vertx.core.net.impl.VertxHandler.channelRead(VertxHandler.java:164)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
> at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:93)
> at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.extensions.WebSocketServerExtensionHandler.channelRead(WebSocketServerExtensionHandler.java:101)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
> at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xUpgradeToH2CHandler.channelRead(Http1xUpgradeToH2CHandler.java:109)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
> at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
> at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324)
> at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
> at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xOrH2CHandler.end(Http1xOrH2CHandler.java:61)
> at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xOrH2CHandler.channelRead(Http1xOrH2CHandler.java:38)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
> at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
> at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
> at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

I have tried delaying pod initialization health check time, but always get the exception only the first time the pod is deployed.
If pod redeploy is made, then all works fine.
So, what should I do to make success pod initialization after openshift cluster starts?

This is my application.properties file configuration:

```
quarkus.http.cors=true
quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=http://keycloak-myproject.192.168.1.110.nip.io/auth/realms/secured-realm
quarkus.oidc.client-id=namaste
```

I'm using Openshift 3.11 and quarkus 1.13.6.Final version

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely to do with Keycloak not ready yet by the time the pod is deployed - `quarkus-oidc` does not try a different connection logic when it is deployed in OpenShift, all it does it always attempts to connect to URL set in `quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url`.
The way to handle it in `1.13.x` is to use a `quarkus.oidc.connection-delay` property, for example, set it to `3M`, etc - `quarkus-oidc` will keep trying to connect for `3M` in this case. Here there is a small race condition that even if Keycloak becomes contactable it may still have not finished loading a custom realm file as has been discovered recently by a Quarkus user - a PR will be opened soon to resolve this particular issue.
The best option is to try `2.0.0.CR3` - there `quarkus-oidc` will recover even if the connection to Keycloak has failed at the start up.
HTH

Comment: Hello @Sergey. Thanks for reply. Tried both suggestions but no luck :(. By adding quarkus.oidc.connection-delay property causes pod to keep throwing the same exception continuously and doesn't start. And when migrated to 2.0.0.CR3 got this exception: "OpenId Connect Provider configuration metadata is not configured and can not be discovered" and also the pod doesn't start.  For both cases after pod redeploy, all starts to work fine

Comment: Related question: [8532430](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68532430/how-to-set-up-oidc-connection-to-keycloak-in-quarkus-on-kubernetes)