# How to set up OIDC connection to Keycloak in Quarkus on Kubernetes

Tags: java, kubernetes, keycloak, openid-connect, quarkus

Has somebody succeeded in setting up OIDC connection to Keycloack in a Quarkus app deployed in a Kubernetes cluster ?
Could you clarify how does the `connection-delay` (and other related parameters) work ?
([Here is the documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-openid-connect) I tried to follow)

In our env (Quarkus 1.13.3.Final, Keycloak 12.0.4) we have such config:

> quarkus.oidc.connection-delay: 6M
> quarkus.oidc.connection-timeout: 30S
> quarkus.oidc.tenant-id: testTenant-01

And these msgs appear in pod's log when it's being started:

> 2021-07-26 14:44:22,523 INFO  [main] [OidcRecorder.java:264] -
> Connecting to IDP for up to 180 times every 2 seconds
> 2021-07-26
> 14:44:24,142 DEBUG [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1]
> [OidcRecorder.java:115] - 'testTenant-01' tenant initialization has failed:
> 'OpenId Connect Provider configuration metadata is not configured and
> can not be discovered'. Access to resources protected by this tenant
> will fail with HTTP 401.

(... following log comes later as the pod is running ...)

> 2021-07-27 06:11:54,261 DEBUG [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0]
> [DefaultTenantConfigResolver.java:112] - Tenant 'null' is not
> initialized
> 2021-07-27 06:11:54,262 ERROR
> [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] [QuarkusErrorHandler.java:101] - HTTP
> Request to /q/health/live failed, error id:
> 89f83d1d-894c-4fed-9995-0d42d60cec17-2: io.quarkus.oidc.OIDCException:
> Tenant configuration has not been resolved    at
> io.quarkus.oidc.runtime.OidcAuthenticationMechanism.resolve(OidcAuthenticationMechanism.java:61)
> at
> io.quarkus.oidc.runtime.OidcAuthenticationMechanism.authenticate(OidcAuthenticationMechanism.java:40)
> at
> io.quarkus.oidc.runtime.OidcAuthenticationMechanism_ClientProxy.authenticate(OidcAuthenticationMechanism_ClientProxy.zig:189)
> at
> io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.security.HttpAuthenticator.attemptAuthentication(HttpAuthenticator.java:100)
> at
> io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.security.HttpAuthenticator_ClientProxy.attemptAuthentication(HttpAuthenticator_ClientProxy.zig:157)
> at
> io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.security.HttpSecurityRecorder$2.handle(HttpSecurityRecorder.java:101)
> at
> io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.security.HttpSecurityRecorder$2.handle(HttpSecurityRecorder.java:51)
> at
> io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1038)

Questions:

1. Any way how to find out what metadata are missing ?
2. Can I somehow change the 2s period between connection attempts ?
3. Any relation between connection-delay and connection-timeout ?
4. It failed after cca 2s - does it mean that it fails immediately in the 1st attempt, or has it finished 180 attempts so fast ?
5. Does `DefaultTenantConfigResolver` get tenant from different resource than `OidcRecorder` in initialization, i.e. should tenant be configured at multiple places ?

Comment: Yes, I've been running quarkus with keycloak using the oicd plugin for at least a year. Which is your authorization scheme?, are you going to use protected resources or just validate JWT tokens and retrieve information from them ?

Comment: As response to the general error it looks like you are missing the multitenancy configuration with the non-tenant config. This means that as you can see in the stack tracke no-tenant is being resolved so no configuration is loaded from your properties or your tenant resolver, this seems to be the cause of your error

Comment: @karelss We need to manage access to API, mainly using RolesAllowed annotation.

Comment: _no-tenant is being resolved so no configuration is loaded from your properties_ - could you clarify it please ?  In the log msg at 2021-07-26 14:44:24,142 you can see that tenant is loaded, but later at 2021-07-27 06:11:54,261 it says the tenant is null.

Comment: True I missed that log entry, can you post your application properties file or final configuration to let check what you have ?, just put <password> and <url> where private information appears

Comment: @karelss Thanks for your feedback, finally the cause was identified - see the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Finally made it work. Caused by incorrect auth-server-url which **is not clear at all from the log messages**.

```
quarkus.oidc.client-id: my-app
quarkus.oidc.enabled: true
quarkus.oidc.connection-delay: 6M
quarkus.oidc.connection-timeout: 30S
quarkus.oidc.tenant-id: testTenant-01
quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url: ${keycloak.url}/auth/realms/${quarkus.oidc.tenant-id}
```

The URL format is emphasized in [Quarkus doc](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-openid-connect#quarkus-oidc_quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url): *Note if you work with Keycloak OIDC server, make sure the base URL is in the following format: https://host:port/auth/realms/{realm} where {realm} has to be replaced by the name of the Keycloak realm*

Comment: Nice you have found the issue, this happens to me also the first time I setup the project, in my case i had to put the oidc plugin log level to ALL to find the issue